# Is it possible to find an element by the role attribute in protractor?

Tags: node.js, protractor

As I say in the title, is it possible to find an element by the role attribute in protractor? The attribute is as follows:

`role = "menuitem"`

I don't know if this item can be found by its attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here are examples of that:

```
$('[role = "menuitem"]'); // get one element
$$('[role = "menuitem"]'); // get list of the elements

element(by.css('[role = "menuitem"]')); // get one element
element.all(by.css('[role = "menuitem"]')); // get list of the elements
```